# How to split data querying from the Db to prevent querying the whole Db

Tags: database, frontend

thanks in advance.

I've got a Db like this:
[Database model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6ddD.png)

It was modeled using an ORM and than displayed with a small desktop app.

The goal of this app is to **send the drawers to the different places based on what they contains**.
(A place can contains one drawer at a time or be empty)

Since the main view of the app will allow to execute this movements, it will need these informations:

- Current context
- State of the places [with drawer/Empty]
- State of the drawers [if in a place][its content (so the sheets) and relative informations]

To help the user identify the drawers they will be grouped by tower.
Each drawer will have the description of its content: a sheet and its material.

As you can see all the tables are required at the same time.

The **question** is: *How to query only certain data instead of the entire database?*
Probably a better approach is to edit the view to be able to show only some of these informations at the same time, but i struggle to came up with such a design without it being more tedious to the end user.

My .Net app use EF6 and now it basically use a single query with nested include instructions.
I fear that in a real scenario this approach will slow down my app very fast.

Thank you.

Ps.
Obviously redirecting me to design patterns or other material that can help me it's very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't about querying yet. First you need to store it right.

1. You have a bunch of circular dependencies in your schema:
   `drawer -> place; place -> drawer`, `tower -> drawer; tower -> context -> place-> drawer -> tower`. You should get rid of these. After you make your schema is a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) you can use deal with filtering easily and also avoid consistency problems.
2. Start with a simple [star schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema) and iterate over it.
3. If you face performance problems, consider [denormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization).
4. Read a book about database design/modeling or take an online course.

Comment: Thank you, I looked at some of the resources you shared and I understood the problems with the DB design. I'll try to improve it before continue.